# new Random(seed) generates ordered sequence of numbers

Tags: java, random

There is interesting quiz which I didn't find answer yet

```
    Random random = new Random(-6732303926L);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int randomNumber = random.nextInt(10);
        System.out.print(randomNumber);
    }
```

OUTPUT: `0123456789`

My question is not about why random generates the same output all time. It's clear from documentation and, for example, from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28934099/1834131).

My question is why it generates ordered numbers?
Could someone describe how does it work?

Comment: that seed just happens to generate the perfectly possible set of random numbers (0 .. 9). It's like rolling a d10 ten times, it's possible to get 0,1,2,3..9but unlikely. If you do get it though and remember the seed that you started with you will always get it again

Comment: And the 11th number won't be following this, randomness can happen to show beautiful things, see with the universe ? ;-)

Comment: Found quite good answer on my question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/7926516/1834131 . And now it became obvious for me